# Link to individual mails in gmail

Tags: gmail, web-crawler, gmail-imap, jakarta-mail

I want to download all emails in a gmail account and also want to get the unique url which will open the exact mail in gmail, off course with authentication. I tried using javax.mail imap library but Imap probably doesn't supports anything like it.

I can use "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom" gmail feeds. but won't give me entire email and it only gives unread email and I don't want to miss any email

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this if you are using Google Apps for Business/Education.  If you are, you can access the Gmail inbox feed (Atom) by using OAuth.  OAuth can also be used to access Gmail via IMAP - you can then have complete access to the IMAP server programmatically, see [Gmail IMAP and SMTP using OAuth](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/).

Google has extended IMAP to allow developers to provide a more Gmail-like experience via IMAP, see: [(Gmail IMAP Extensions, X-GM-EXT-1)](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/imap/).

The unique message (X-GM-MSGID) and unique thread (X-GM-THRID) ids can be used to produce links to Gmail messages directly - you just have to hex encode the id long (e.g. Long.toHexString(x_gm_msgId)).  Your link will then need need to be in the form of:

```
http://mail.google.com/mail?account_id=ACCOUNT_ID_HERE&message_id=MESSAGE_ID_HERE&view=conv&extsrc=atom
```

supplying **ACCOUNT_ID_HERE** (something like *user@someplace.com*) and **MESSAGE_ID_HERE** as appropriate.

I have been working in this area and think you might find my project useful, see: [java-gmail-imap](http://code.google.com/p/java-gmail-imap/).

[NB: URLs formatted as above do not work on Gmail's mobile site (at least on iPhone/Safari).]

Answer (score 0):

https://mail.google.com/mail/#all/HexEncodeMessageID
replace the HexEncodeMessageID part with the ID. You get it, when you open the email in a new window (use the pop out icon in the upper right corner.
The id looks like this: search=inbox&th=**1426b8f59e003aa0**

Comment: I think he wanted to be able to do it without hitting the website at all.

Answer (score -1):

I'm fairly confident this is not possible - that there is no reliable way to get the unique URL that'll lead to a single email in Gmail. I'd love to hear otherwise!

I do believe it is possible to get a URL that will lead to the Gmail thread containing the message - but you have no control over which message(s) are "expanded" in this threaded display.

Comment: My purpose will be solved even if I can get URL to message thread. Can you help me out with it?But, Greplin is doing something which takes you to the unique email, expands it.